# Refrigerate Non-Alcoholic beer?

Tags: taste, storage, flavor, temperature, non-alcoholic

Should non-alcoholic beer be refrigerated to preserve it? How long does non-alcoholic beer last when not refrigerated?

Answer (score 1):

Refrigeration has little to do with preservation.  As a food product beer and NA beer are pretty strictly regulated for safety so as long as the rubber in the cap maintains a seal it should stay sterile.  Refrigeration is mostly for taste and carbonation.